# ajaxSubmit not working IE9. All other browsers seem fine

Tags: mailchimp, ajaxsubmit

I have a simple (naked) MailChimp email signup form that I can't get to work in IE9. Every other browser seems fine. I know this question has been asked before but in various different circumstances. We are using JQuery Form Plugin.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
       $(form).ajaxSubmit();
        /*DO SOME OTHER STUFF*/
      }
     });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//#####.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=#############&amp;id=##########" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
    <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-MMERGE10">State </label>
        <select name="MMERGE10" class="" id="mce-MMERGE10">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    
        </select>
    </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_8bd18de15624fc1fb89b76d51_29d17890f0" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```